# Balanced attenuator instead of balun

Tags: attenuator, balun

Is it OK to use balanced attenuator for impedance matching instead of balun? I need an attenuator anyway, so why use both?

Original schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWs6z5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

New design: skip 4:1 balun, recalculate attenuator resistors considering input impedance 200 Ohm

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnSdqJ.png)</sup>

Comment: Which side of this is supposed to be unbalanced? The source?

Comment: Your schematics need a ground symbol to show where the imbalance is located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is it OK to use balanced attenuator for impedance matching instead of
> balun? I need an attenuator anyway, so why use both?*

<sub>A balun is a word composite. The first three letter (Bal) mean balanced. The last two letters (un) mean unbalanced so, when we use a balun we are converting a balanced signal to an unbalanced signal (or vice versa).</sub>

Given that you are probably using the term incorrectly (I'd call it a transformer), you are quite right that if you need attenuation then you can use a resistive impedance matching network without the transformer.